# Texcount.pl with Texmaker word.count file not found error

Tags: texmaker, word-count

I'm trying to get texcount.pl http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/ to work inside Texmaker but I get the error about the word.count that is not found. The documentations says that I have to add `--shell-escape` to solve the problem but I don't know where to put that. Does anyone know?

Comment: Just to clearify: Are you trying to run TeXcount from Texmaker as a user command, or are you trying to get TeX/LaTeX to execute TeXcount from within the document so the TeXcount is executed every time the document is typeset? The --shell-escape option is a TeX/LaTeX option required by the latter to be allowed to execute shell commands from within the TeX/LaTeX document.

Comment: According to the manual (http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02) there's "Configure Texmaker" -> "Commands" which brings you to where the LaTeX command (with options) is specified.

Comment: I'm trying to get Latex to execute texcount within the document. I currently have this latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex in my latex command. Where exactly do I put shell-escape because I tried several places and it gives an error.

Comment: You could try "latex -interaction=nonstop --shell-escape %.tex" and if that doesn't work try replacing "--shell-escape" with "--enable-write18".

Comment: Should it be nonstopmode or is nonstop what I should put? I tried with nonstopmode and both shell-escape and enable-write18 at the place you suggest but it still returns an error

Comment: Sorry, my misprint: should have been nonstopmode if that was what was before. Can you try running latex on your document from the command line with the options to see what happens: if the problem is LaTeX of Texmaker related.

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the answer (so far):

Running TeXcount, or any other OS command, from TeX or LaTeX is done by entering code similar to this

```
\immediate\write18{texcount test.tex > test.sum}
```

in the TeX/LaTeX document (which I've checked and work when I do it from TeXworks). A somewhat improved version of this is provided on the [help pages of TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#latexcall)

```
\immediate\write18{texcount \jobname.tex -out=\jobname.sum}
```

provided you have a more recent version of TeXcount. In either case, this requires texcount to be in the path, or the OS will not find it.

TeX and LaTeX (and other TeX versions) will by default not execute `\write18` commands unless you give the options `--shell-escape` (for TeX I believe) or `--enable-write18` (for LaTeX I believe).

Changing the LaTeX options is explained in the [Texmaker manual](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02).

Note that TeXcount may have slightly different filenames from system to system depending on where you got it from: `texcount` or `texcount.pl`, and I know some have also compiled it into `texcount.exe`.

If it still doesn't work, you should try to figure out which thing goes wrong. Try running LaTeX from the command line instead of Texmaker to see if that works or what errors are given. Or try executing something like `dir > dir.txt` in the `\write18` to see if you can get it to execute at all.