# Texmaker user commands: output to log/messages

Tags: texmaker, word-count, terminal-output

I'm using several User Commands with texmaker on Mac OS X. My problem is, that some of the commands are just shellscripts, or other programs like `texcount` that produces output to the STDOUT. Is there a way to tell texmaker, that the output generated by user commands should be displayed inside the log/message view of texmaker?

e.g. I have a user command for word count `/usr/texbin/texcount %.tex -inc -sum` that runs properly on the terminal, but doesn't produce any output to texmaker's log window when ran as a user command.

thx!

Comment: related [Texcount.pl with Texmaker word.count file not found error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69627/15717)

Comment: I think this question is quite clear. In fact, it's a perfect description of exactly what my problem is with Texmaker.