# make texmaker show compile error output (Message/Log) with custom lualatex user-build-command

Tags: errors, luatex, compiling, texmaker

i want to compile documents with a lualatex user build command within texmaker on mac os x.

here is my command:

```
/usr/texbin/lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|open %.pdf
```

It compiles good. the problem is, that i dont get any error messages (feedback) in the 'Messages/Log' window when a compiling error occurs. which is not nice if trying to debug.

The output i get is:

> Process started
>
> Process exited with error(s)

thats all.

any ideas to show the error output ?

the solution from an other post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69627/texcount-pl-with-texmaker-word-count-file-not-found-error) didn't work. which is basically adding `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18`

Comment: This User command Option: `lualatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` works for me. **My guess**: Uncheck the `Use Build Subdirectory for Output files` option in `Configure TeXmaker`-->`Commands` and make sure the `same-file-name.log` file is created in the **same** folder where `.tex` exists otherwise TeXmaker cannot read it.

Answer (score 1):

All right. turns out that, I dont know why, after a compilation error occurred I now need to click the "view Log" button at the left hand side bar of the Messages/Log window in order to see the error list. At the beginning this happend automatically and i didn't had to click anything to see the error list. although this is annoying, this problem might be considered as "solved".

Comment: Yes, you are right. When `lualatex` compilation is User defined (via `User Commands` option), Texmaker is not able to unable to parse the error `.log` automatically(Like it does for `pdflatex` with red errors) unless one presses the `View Log` button on Bottom left panel bar. May be you should [report it](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) with this thread. It's a possible enhancement/feature request for TeXmaker to include a `lualatex` compilation option or include an automatic parsing of `.log`.

Comment: @texenthusiast done. https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1097&q=lualatex&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary