# TexMaker, Message/Log file does not show by default when use pdflatex (F6). Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: texmaker

Each time I use pdflatex(F6), if there is errors, only the following two lines are shown.

```
Process started
Process exited with error(s)
```

I have to go to "View" / "Message/Log file" (F10) to see the error information. I find a related [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137167/make-texmaker-show-compile-error-output-message-log-with-custom-lualatex-user) which blame this by using luatex, however, which is not my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the "quick build" command (F1) with the "pdflatex + view pdf" mode (Configure texmaker -> Quick build)